# Serialize C# object into JSON which contains a List

Tags: c#, database, ado.net

What I'm trying to do is to get some data from my database (customers order with all items he ordered) convert it to JSON that contains a list of said items so I can send it with a POST request.
I want to create a JSON object which would contain details of customers order, and a list of products contained in that order. This is how I want my JSON to look like:

```
{
  "account_code": "00000",       
  "advance_payment": false,       
  "date": [today's date],
  "order_items": 
   [
     {
       "item_id": 0, 
       "product_Price ": "105.00",  
       "order_Item_Rebate: "",     
       "product_code": "000001",   
       "quantity": 1
     },
     {
       "item_id": 1, 
       "product_Price ": "55.00",  
       "price": "",     
       "product_code": "000002",   
       "quantity": 5
     },
     {
       "item_id": 2, 
       "product_Price ": "15.00",  
       "price": "",     
       "product_code": "000003",   
       "quantity": 3
     }
   ]
}
```

But what I'm getting is this:

```
{
  "account_code": "00000",       
  "advance_payment": false,       
  "date": [today's date],
  "order_items": 
   [
     {
       "item_id": 0, 
       "roduct_Price ": "105.00",  
       "order_Item_Rebate: "",     
       "product_code": "000001",   
       "quantity": 1
     }
   ]
},
{
  "account_code": "00000",       
  "advance_payment": false,       
  "date": [today's date],
  "order_items": 
   [
     {
       "item_id": 1, 
       "roduct_Price ": "55.00",  
       "price": "",     
       "product_code": "000002",   
       "quantity": 5
     }
   ]
},
{
  "account_code": "00000",       
  "advance_payment": false,       
  "date": [today's date],
  "order_items": 
   [
     {
       "item_id": 2, 
       "product_Price ": "15.00",  
       "price": "",     
       "product_code": "000003",   
       "quantity": 3
     }
   ]
}
```

Instead of one JSON object with a list of items, I get multiple JSON object for the same customer(account_code).

I'm getting this data from database using ADO.NET and I read this data with SqlDataReader. Inside SqlDataReader I created a new object and filled it with details about my order. It all works, but problem is order_items which should be a list of all items from the order. I want one order with multiple items in it, not a different order for every item.
Using code below I am able to get data from my database, but I don't know how to group order_items with the order they should be in.

```
List<OrderModel> orderList = new List<OrderModel>();
using (SqlDataReader rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            OrderModel order = new OrderModel()
                            {
                                Account_code = rdr[0].ToString(),
                                Advance_payment = false,
                                Date = DateTime.Now.Date,
                                Order_Items = new List<Order_items>()
                                    {
                                     //Here is where I should do something instead of creating new
                                     //Order_items, but I don't know what
                                        new Order_items()
                                        {
                                            Order_Item_Rebate = rdr[1].ToString(),
                                            Product_Price = rdr[2].ToString(),
                                            Product_Code = rdr[3].ToString(),
                                            Quantity = rdr[4].ToString()
                                        }
                                    }

                            };
                            orderList.Add(order);
                        }
                        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(orderList);
                        return jsonString;
                    }
```

My OrderModel class looks like this:

```
public class OrderModel
    {
        public string Account_code { get; set; } 
        public bool Advance_payment { get; set; } 
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public List<Order_items> Order_Items { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Order_items
    {
        public string Order_Item_Rebate { get; set; } 
        public string Product_Price { get; set; } 
        public string Product_Code { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

And table from my database looks like this:

| Account_code | Order_Item_Rebate | Product_Price | Product_Code | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00000 | 10 | 105 | 000001 | 1 |
| 00000 | 5 | 55 | 000002 | 5 |
| 00000 | 15 | 15 | 000002 | 3 |

I have seen similar questions and people were advising to use an array of dictionaries, but I'm not sure if I understand how would they help. I'm new with this, so I'm sorry if question is not really smart.

Comment: The problem is that you are creating a new `OrderModel` for each `Order_items`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem is that you're creating a new `OrderModel` in each iteration of the `while (rdr.Read())` loop. The most straight forward way to approach this would be to simply check for an existing `OrderModel` in `orderList` based on the `Account_code`, and create a new instance of `OrderModel` only if you don't find one. For example...

```
List<OrderModel> orderList = new List<OrderModel>();
using (SqlDataReader rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        // Check to see if there is already an instance of OrderModel with the
        // account code in the list.
        OrderModel order = orderList.FirstOrDefault(om => om.Account_code == rdr[0].ToString());
        if (order == null)
        {
            // If there isn't create a new instance of OrderModel and add it to
            // the list.
            order = new OrderModel
            {
                Account_code = rdr[0].ToString(),
                Advance_payment = false,
                Date = DateTime.Now.Date,
                Order_Items = new List<Order_items>()
            };
            orderList.Add(order);
        }
        
        // Now, just add the new item to Order_Items.
        order.Order_Items.Add(new Order_item
        {
            Order_Item_Rebate = rdr[1].ToString(),
            Product_Price = rdr[2].ToString(),
            Product_Code = rdr[3].ToString(),
            Quantity = rdr[4].ToString()
        });
    }
    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(orderList);
    return jsonString;
}
```

The performance might be poor, especially as `orderList` grows larger, since you're iterating `orderList` once per iteration of the `while` loop. But, this basic approach should work. Instead of creating one `OrderModel` per iteration of the `while` loop, you need to make sure that you only create on per `Account_code` in your result set.

If you have control over the query itself, you can order the results by `Account_code` to address the performance.

```
List<OrderModel> orderList = new List<OrderModel>();
using (SqlDataReader rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
    OrderModel order = null;
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        if (order == null || order.Account_code != rdr[0].ToString())
        {
            // The order is null, meaning that this is the first order model to be processed.
            // Or, the order's account code is different than the current account code on the result set, meaning we have begun processing a new order.
            // In either case, you need to add a new order to the list so
            // you can start filling in its items.
            order = new OrderModel
            {
                Account_code = rdr[0].ToString(),
                Advance_payment = false,
                Date = DateTime.Now.Date,
                Order_Items = new List<Order_items>()
            };
            orderList.Add(order);
        }        
        
        // Now, just add the new item to Order_Items.
        order.Order_Items.Add(new Order_item
        {
            Order_Item_Rebate = rdr[1].ToString(),
            Product_Price = rdr[2].ToString(),
            Product_Code = rdr[3].ToString(),
            Quantity = rdr[4].ToString()
        });
    }
    var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(orderList);
    return jsonString;
}
```

The above approach will only work if you can order the results of the query by account code.

Comment: Thank you, it works great! Performance is not really a problem because there is not that much data and there will never be.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL query will result in "flattened" data, so you need to group it yourself. Something along this lines:

```cs
var orderDict = new Dictionary<string, OrderModel>(); // mapping from account code to order object
while (rdr.Read())
{
   var accCode = rdr[0].ToString();
   
   // if no object previously added - add a new one 
   if(!orderDict.TryGetValue(accCode, out var order))
   {
       order = new OrderModel()
       {
           Account_code = accCode ,
           Advance_payment = false,
           Date = DateTime.Now.Date,
           Order_Items = new List<Order_items>()
       };
       orderDict[accCode] = order;
   }

   // add details from current result line to order 
   order.Order_Items.Add(new Order_items() {...});
}

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(orderDict.Values); // serialize only values, not the whole dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Define your `order` variable outside the `while` loop.

```
var order = new OrderModel()
{
    Account_code = rdr[0].ToString(),
    Advance_payment = false,
    Date = DateTime.Now.Date,
    Order_Items = new List<Order_items>()
};
```

2. Parse order items inside the `while` loop

```
using (SqlDataReader rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        var item = new Order_items()
        {
            Order_Item_Rebate = rdr[1].ToString(),
            Product_Price = rdr[2].ToString(),
            Product_Code = rdr[3].ToString(),
            Quantity = rdr[4].ToString()
        };
        order.Order_Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

3. Serialize the only `OrderModel` after the loop

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order);
return jsonString;
```